# Why does the jackknife reduce bias

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Given a sample $\textbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, define $\textbf{x}_{(-i)}$ as the sample values excluding sample $x_i$. That is,
$$
\textbf{x}_{(-i)} = (x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, \ldots x_n).
$$
Now given estimator $T(\textbf{x})$ of parameter $\tau(\theta)$ based on the sample $\textbf{x}$, Lehmann and Casella (in the 2nd edition of Theory of Point Estimation) define the **jackknifed version** of $T(\textbf{x})$ as
$$
T_J(\textbf{x}) = nT(\textbf{x}) - \frac{n -1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n T\left(\textbf{x}_{(-i)}\right).
$$
They claim that if $E[T(\textbf{x})] = \tau(\theta) + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, then $E[T_J(\textbf{x})] = \tau(\theta) + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$. Can someone explain why the jackknifed version of $T(\textbf{x})$ has lower asymptotic bias then the original estimator?

Comment: From the little math I know ... me $2$ drachmas ... $\frac{1}{n}$ has been replaced by $\frac{1}{n^2}$. This implies that whatever statistic this calculates, the usual method *overestimates* and the *jack knife* corrects for that bias. "Asymptote" is the correct word.

Comment: I wonder why it wasn't $\frac{1}{2n}$. Have you heard of *Benford's Law*? and $2^2 = 2 + 2 = 2(2)$. Is it *just* a *fudge factor*?

Comment: In this link: http://fs2.american.edu/baron/www/627/Handouts/Jackknife.pdf, the author claimed instead, if $$ \mathbb{E}[T(x)] = \tau(\theta) + \dfrac{a_1}{n} + \dfrac{a_2}{n^2} + ... $$ then, it can be shown that $$\mathbb{E}[T_J(x)] = \tau(\theta) + \dfrac{a_2}{n^2} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-3})$$

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn thanks. That's a special case of the result I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, but it requires a constraint slightly stronger than the original problem statement. In the original statement, they claim the result is true if $E[T(\textbf{x})] = \tau(\theta) + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$. I was getting hung up on pathological cases, like:
$$
E[T(\textbf{x})] = \tau(\theta) + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^{1.5}},
$$
and I don't believe the result is actually true in such cases. If you assume the slightly stronger constraint
$$
E[T(\textbf{x})] = \tau(\theta) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{b_i}{n^i},
$$
the result becomes provable. Note that in many practical cases, the estimator will be representable in this constrained form of $O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ functions, so this extra constraint does not dillute the power of the jackknife method in reducing bias. Here's the proof:
$$
\begin{align}
E[T_J(\textbf{x})] &= E\left[nT(\textbf{x}) - \frac{n -1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n T\left(\textbf{x}_{(-j)}\right)\right]\\
&= nE[T(\textbf{x})] - \frac{n -1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n E\left[T\left(\textbf{x}_{(-j)}\right)\right] \\
&= n\left(\tau(\theta) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{b_i}{n^i} \right) - \frac{n -1}{n}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \left(\tau(\theta) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{b_i}{(n-1)^i}\right)\right) \\
&=n\tau(\theta) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{b_i}{n^{i-1}} - (n-1)\left(\tau(\theta) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{b_i}{(n-1)^i}\right) \\
&= \tau(\theta) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\frac{b_i}{n^{i-1}} - \frac{b_i}{(n-1)^{i-1}}\right) \\
&= \tau(\theta) + \left(b_1 - b_1\right) + \sum_{i=2}^\infty \left(\frac{b_i}{n^{i-1}} - \frac{b_i}{(n-1)^{i-1}}\right) \\
&= \tau(\theta)+ \sum_{i=2}^\infty b_i\frac{(n-1)^{i-1} - n^{i-1}}{n^{i-1}(n-1)^{i-1}}
\end{align}
$$
Letting
$$
c_i = \frac{(n-1)^{i-1} - n^{i-1}}{n^{i-1}(n-1)^{i-1}},
$$
it's not hard to see from a binomial expansion in the numerator that $c_i = O\left(\frac{1}{n^i}\right)$, so
$$
E[T_J(\textbf{x})] = \tau(\theta) + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$